# IP address apparently changing every second. Thrown of web site and cannot launch XAMPP

Tags: apache-http-server, ip, xampp, godaddy

I am flummoxed. If I try to log on the my Cpanel page at GoDaddy I get "You have successfully logged in." and then LITERALLY 1-2 seconds later "Your IP address has changed. Please log in again." (It is well less than 3 seconds every time.)

At about the same time this started happening XAMPP refused to start Apache saying:

*Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.

    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,

    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check

    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues

    If you need more help, copy and post this

    entire log window on the forums*

I tried looking at error logs but couldn't see anything recent or apparently useful (I am new to Windows Event Viewer but could not see anything their either - but I was completely confused).

This is a brand new machine and I had recently added AVG antivirus. I thought it might be that but turned AVG off but still hit the two problems.

I am pretty sure they are interrelated but I cannot find anything relevant going after GoDaddy or XAMPP.

Grateful for any pointers.

PS I tried changing ports for the Apache problem but it made no difference. Also thought it might be PIA VPN so uninstalled it but no improvement.

Comment: What address do you see at sites like echo.opera.com or ipv6-test.com if you keep refreshing the site?

Comment: grawity. Thanks for that. It was v weird. On individual tabs it seemed to be sticking with the same IP, occasionally changing and then staying on that IP for a while. But new tabs caused a new IP 90% of the time. I thought tabs = local browser... Started deleting Chrome extensions and voila! Will try and find which extension it was but a million thanks for your pointer it really help me think a bit more clearly.

Comment: Is your ISP perhaps using carrier-grade NAT? Is there anything about connection issues in your router’s/modem’s log?

Comment: @BeNice: Do all those IPs belong to your ISP, or to a VPN provider?

Comment: Sorry my SOLUTION was wrong. I once again cannot get on to GoDaddy. I've tried this with Edge and Chrome on 2 machines. When I use opera I think I am getting a solid single IP but when I look at ipv6 site it sometimes changes to a 213 IP. The opera one seems to show Remote: 82.69.63.31 44341 fairly consistently but last 5 digits changing sometimes (not sure what they are). Sorry I have to go to doctors. Will try another network and see how that goes. To update this am I better to edit the main question or keep on doing changes here. I think it will get v confused if I keep doing this here..

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I spoke too soon. The XAMPP Apache problem is NOT solved. As they started at about the same time I assumed they were connected. Looks like the were not.

**LOGGING IN TO WEBSITE AND BEING IMMEDIATELY THROWN OFF SOLVED**  (Apache not)
This error was caused by a Chrome extension (possibly PIA, JetBrains - not sure but will try to track down).

Thanks to @grawity for his pointer to [echo.opera.com](http://echo.opera.com) which made checking IPs much easier.

If you came this way because of a similar error please leave a comment if you solve the problem. Between us we might be able to track down problem extensions.

PS A completely fresh reinstall of XAMPP fixed that ... for now.